# Python Random String Gen Problem, How do i add "-" between every 3 chars

Tags: python

If I wanted to make a random string gen and make it look like perhaps a gift card gen, example: `543-463-6345` how would I do so? I have tried to use:

```py
('').join(random.choices(string.digits + string.digits + string.digits + string.digits ,
                                       k=10)), " | Invalid - CODE")
```

I need to add "-" between every 3 characters and then have one with 4
like this 543-463-6345

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to just add a `-` after every 3rd character for an arbitrarily long string, you could use a loop (note that this doesn't handle your 4-character special case):

```
>>> s = "5434636345"
>>> "-".join(s[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(s), 3))
'543-463-634-5'
```

If you have a fixed number of digits that you want to format in a specific way, I'd just use an f-string:

```
>>> f"{s[:3]}-{s[3:6]}-{s[6:]}"
'543-463-6345'
```

although you could build an exception like "have the final group take any remainder" into your loop with a bit of effort:

```
>>> "-".join(s[i*3:i*3+3 if i*3+5 < len(s) else len(s)] for i in range(0, len(s) // 3))
'543-463-6345'
```